# Unsure why my 0x transaction failed (more details inside)

Tags: solidity, 0x

I've written a simple contract tries to swap a few 0x pairs, for doing simple arbs or other 3 way trades.

However, when I get the quotes from their API https://0x.org/docs/api (in serial, which takes about 3-4 seconds), by the time I send the transaction to the chain it reverts.

Here's the transaction:

https://ethtx.info/mainnet/0x0c615e69766bfae68ea8afcb8d48b6456ba5fb09822abcf1e9326b52e112c22d

Can anyone help me figure out *WHY* this reverts? I'm assuming its because perhaps someone has already taken the trade? I can see where it reverts but I'm not 100% sure how to determine why it reverted here in the `transferFrom` function when executing the trade.

Thanks!

Comment: Please verify your contract on [etherscan](https://etherscan.io/address/0xd1362d17e7a34cb5298e61eb9eb06299b3253f5c#code).

Comment: Done! Thanks for responding :)

Comment: Somehow I think it has to do with liquidity disappearing from the destination address as the transaction is sent to chain. Sometimes it sends fine, sometimes specific swap calls fail (within the contract)

Comment: Here's another example of a transaction, here it fails as well with the swapping back from swapped currency to weth. http://ethtx.info/mainnet/0xd3d70f6cc15b351afe1a853a95bc672da223b323a664b2bd919fd264d94d4300

Comment: So weird... https://ethtx.info/mainnet/0x519c68cff16ea9e5de8d1c0e4990eac02a512b68de1fc70f5914ca6293893612 This one cant even transfer the ETH... I should probably stop wasting money on fees lol - but this doesnt happen on Kovan!

Comment: Seems like that first WETH transferfrom is the common denominator in all of them